# Truncated Completely Positive Trace Preserving (CPTP) maps

Tags: operators, quantum-information, quantum-computer, density-operator, time-evolution

Let us consider the the Liouville equation of a level $N$-system with density matrix $\rho$ together with its standard properties (positive semi-definite, unit trace, etc). The evolution of the system reads
$$
\partial_t \rho = \mathcal{L}[\rho] = -i[H,\rho] + \sum_i (L_i\rho L_i^\dagger -\tfrac{1}{2}[L^\dagger_iL_i,\rho]),
$$
where $L_i$ are th dissipative jump operators. This all is pretty standard.

Now assume one wants to know if after some discrete time $\Delta t$, $\rho(t+\Delta t)$ is also a density matrix, that is whether the discretized version of the Liouvillian operator $\mathcal{L}$ is a **Completely Positive Trace Preserving (CPTP) map**.

**It is known** that Kraus sum operators are CPTP maps. Recall that a Kraus sum operator $U$ is one that can be written as
$$
U(\rho) = \sum_{i=1}^{N^2} V_i\rho V_i^\dagger.
$$

Now, assume that I can find a way to express (to 1st order) the discrete time evolution as such:
$$
\rho(t + \Delta t)= \sum_{i=1}^{M} V_i\rho V_i^\dagger \, \Delta t + \text{ higher order terms}
$$
but with $M \neq N^2$ and $M \leq N^2$.

**Question: Would this then qualify as a Kraus sum representation proving that at 1st order what I have is a CPTP map?**

Comment: The sum in the Kraus representation need not go to N^2.

Comment: Can you expand on this?

Comment: I'm not sure there's much to expand. A Kraus sum representation of a CPTP map is of the form $\mathcal E(\rho)=\sum_{\ell=1}^L K_\ell^\dagger \rho K_\ell$, where $L$ can have *any* value for $\mathcal E$ to be a CPTP map. (Conversely, there is always *a* Kraus representation where $L\le d^2$, with $d$ the dimension of the Hilbert space.) -- So the claim that the sum has to go to $N^2$ for it to be a Kraus representation is simply not correct.